# accessing an azure AD via its LDAP url

Tags: ldap, azure-activedirectory

We wish to use azure AD for authentication for our application which is also hosted on azure.

How to determine the LDAP url to connect to? When we create a new Azure AD, there is no location on the azure portal that tells you what the ldap url is. We are expecting something of the form ldap://privateip or ldap://domain to be provided when an Azure AD is created but that doesn't seem to be present or clearly visible in the portal hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

Historically Azure AD (AAD) has been a directory for user authentication but has lacked the LDAP directory features that a regular Windows Server AD provides. Depending on application type and authentication needs there are various ways to use Azure AD. Some of them are completly transparent like the [App Service authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication), other solutions requires you to work with the Azure AD Graph API.

Regarding LDAP; Have you had a chance to look at [Azure AD Domain Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-configure-secure-ldap). It is possible that this serves your purpose if you need LDAP connectivity or has an application directly utilizes LDAP. I've not yet tested this, as we mainly work in the new Azure portal due to EA/CSP subscriptions.

Comment: Will check out azure ad directory services